# Can objects inside iOS coco2d environment be retained?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have several custom obects inside the coco2d environment that needed to be retained. 
so I set

```
      @property(nonatomic, assign) int score;
      @property(nonatomic, assign) Object *obj1;
```

inside my CCLayer scene, I synthesize score and obj1, during the init function I set the value for score, and obj1, however later on , I find score and obj1 have no value or not assigned score=0; and obj1  = 0x0;  what's going on? can things be retained under coco2d environment?

Comment: Use ARC and stop worrying about these things (for the most part).

Answer (score 0):

You may (or may not) need to retain `obj1` depending on how you use it but the problem with `score` points to something else.  The most common cause for that is having two copies of the same object, setting a value in one, and trying to read it in another.  Try logging the value of `self` both where you assign to `score` and where you read it as an unexpected value.  If the addresses show different `self`s that would confirm it.